# find next high / low values within a range of 'n' from a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of numbers from which need to find the next highs / lows within a range of 7 from the previous high/low.

**Range search frequency:   7**
[NextHighLowsWithinFreq7_InRange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12n2k.png)

Above right most column is the answer that am aiming to find...

*Any help is highly appreciated!!*

[Sample Excel file with data is here...](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6jBNABMONOnVVcwWjlBS0FjVjA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you assume that the first one and maybe the last one is a low? And what happens if it doesn't find a low or high within a range of 7?

Comment: @TomSharpe Thank you for getting back! Any solution that achieves this would be great!! As long as its able to find the next Highs / Lows within a range...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been experimenting with this formula

```
=IF(ROW()>MAX(ROW(D$1:D4)*(D$1:D4<>""))+7,"",IF(AND(LEFT(INDEX(D$1:D4,MAX(ROW(D$1:D4)*(D$1:D4<>""))))="L",C4<C5,C6<C5),"H"&RIGHT(INDEX(D$1:D4,MAX(ROW(D$1:D4)*(D$1:D4<>"")))),IF(AND(LEFT(INDEX(D$1:D4,MAX(ROW(D$1:D4)*(D$1:D4<>""))))="H",C4>C5,C6>C5),"L"&RIGHT(INDEX(D$1:D4,MAX(ROW(D$1:D4)*(D$1:D4<>""))))+1,"")))
```

If you assume the first one is a low and put L1 in D4, then put this in D5 and pull it down, it does get the remaining highs and lows except for the last one where there is nothing in the next cell to compare it to. If there is no high or low with the range of 7 cells it will just produce blanks though. Also it would need editing for the case when the numbers get into double digits.

It is an array formula and must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: @RogerH: When I apply the solution to my excel sheet, it says invalid formula... Could you please upload your xls file here, so can re-use the same. Many Thanks BadBoy!

Comment: Could you please upload your solution xls file, when I try to apply the same, I am getting blanks.... Thanks a Ton! BadBoy!

Comment: I've put a screen shot into my answer and you can try downloading the file from https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71397426/LowHigh.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

This formula will give the "High" and "Low" letter points adjacent to the values in Column C :=IF(AND(C6C5,C6>C7),"H","")).

Comment: The above answer was pasted incorrectly. Correction : IF(AND(C5<C4,C5<C6),"L",IF(AND(C5>C4,C5>C6),"H",""))

Answer (score 0):

This is an updated formula to give a sequential count as you indicated : =IF(AND(C50,COUNTIF(D$1:D4,"*L*"),""),IF(AND(C5>C4,C5>C6),"H"&IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D4,"*H*")>0,COUNTIF(D$1:D4,"*H*"),""),"")).

Comment: @Badboy: Pasting is not performing correctly. Updated for sequential count : IF(AND(C5<C4,C5<C6),"L"&IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D4,"*L*")>0,COUNTIF(D$1:D4,"*L*"),""),IF(AND(C5>C4,C5>C6),"H"&IF(COUNTIF(D$1:D4,"*H*")>0,COUNTIF(D$1:D4,"*H*"),""),""))